# SOAPUI HTTP test request fails due to not replacing properties

Tags: soapui

I am using SOAPUI for a few simple tests and I have create the following HTTP GET request:

[http://some_server/basemap/{param0}/{param1}/{param0}_{param1}_16.png](http://some_server/basemap/%7Bparam0%7D/%7Bparam1%7D/%7Bparam0%7D_%7Bparam1%7D_16.png) in soapui 4.5.1.

Param0 en param1 are set in the HTTP test request screen and are replaced by numbers to result in the request http://some_server/basemap/9/7/9_7_16.png to retrieve a png file from a file system. This has worked perfectly in 4.5.1.

Recently I have upgraded and all these tests failed. I get 404 reports with the message:

```
The requested URL /basemap/{param0}/{param1}/{param0}_{param1}_16.png was not found on this server.
```

It seems the properties are not replaced properly.

It has failed to work on 5.0 and 5.2. After reinstalling 4.5.1. it worked perfectly again.

How do I get this to work in 5.2.1?

Comment: Closing: cannot reproduce! See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently soapUI 5.x is a bit more strickt in its syntax checks than 4.x. Or it is a bug in 4.x.

http://some_server/basemap/{param0}/{param1}/{param0}_{param1}_16.png worked in 4.x it did not in 5.x. 
However after changing this url into http://some_server/basemap/${param0}/${param1}/${param0}_${param1}_16.png everything worked again.